# PostgreSQL calculated index for JSON value doesn't work in peewee?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, peewee, database-indexes

I am using peewee to create a PostgreSQL calculated index from a value in a JSON column.
Here is the code

```
idx = Tweet.index(Tweet.data['x'], name='x')
Tweet.add_index(idx)
```

This produces the following SQL which does not work.

`CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS "x" ON "tweet" ("data"->>'x')`

According to the PostgreSQL docs, the JSON expression must be wrapped by **two** sets of parentheses, as follows:

`CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS "x" ON "tweet" (("data"->>'x'))`

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug in Peewee? How can I fix that?

Answer (score -1):

That seems like a postgres bug since it's arbitrary as all hell. In this case, just add the index explicitly using the `SQL()` helper:

```
Tweet.add_index(SQL('create index ...'))
```

Comment: No, it's not a Postgres bug. An index "element" is either a column name or an expression. If it's an expression it must be enclosed in parentheses: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createindex.html This is clearly a bug in the SQL generation of Peewee